# How to pack my library in a self executing function? (emscripten)

Tags: javascript, c++, emscripten

I've created a library in C++ using Embind and Emscripten.

Some hand written JS code is also added to the library using `--pre-js`

The library works. But I would like to rearrange the code, to this:

```
var MYLIB = (function(){
  // ... Original Code ...
  return Module;
})();
```

So the code would not pollute the global namespace, and the code minifier could do better optimizations.

Are there build in functions for this in `emcc` ?

The library will only run in webbrowsers, not in nodejs.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33623682/how-to-use-fs-when-modularize-and-export-name-are-used-in-emscripten

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for are the `MODULARIZE` and `EXPORT_NAME` options. Check the documentation in [settings.js](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/blob/master/src/settings.js).

Quoting from that file:

> // By default we emit all code in a straightforward way into the output
>   // .js file. That means that if you load that in a script tag in a web
>   // page, it will use the global scope. With MODULARIZE set, we will instead emit
>   //
>   //   var EXPORT_NAME = function(Module) {
>   //     Module = Module || {};
>   //     // .. all the emitted code from emscripten ..
>   //     return Module;
>   //   };
>   //
>   // where EXPORT_NAME is from the option of the same name